# gitlab не подгружает картинки после миграции

Tags: git, сервер, gitlab

Перенес базу данных, все работает, но не загружает аватарки которые были загружены локально (не gravatar) на сервере по пути `/srv/docker/gitlab/gitlab/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/user/` у каждого пользователя есть аватар, то же самое в docker контейнере. Но аватары почему-то не грузит.

Comment: Возможные причины: а) аватаров там нет. б) автары грузятся из другой папки, где их нет.

Comment: в) нет прав :) (пятнадцать смволов)

Comment: @Эникейщик, В папке файлы есть, на счет другой папки тоже думал, но по логам когда гружу новую картинку не показывает ничего.

Comment: @Эникейщик У compose файла нет прав? или у кого?